# How to get the last insert ids from laravel 4

Tags: php, laravel, insert, lastinsertid, last-insert-id

I am using laravel 4. I have a table called documents. I am inserting data in the Document table using Document::insert() function.
My code is given below

```
$statuses = array();
foreach($content as $i){
    array_push($statuses, array(
        'user_id' => $user->id,
        'document' => $i->text
    ));
}
$users = Document::insert($statuses);
```

Now I want to get the insert ids. But the $users variable only gives me a boolean variable called true. How can I get the insert ids.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use **[insertGetId()](http://laravel.com/docs/queries#inserts)**

> If the table has an auto-incrementing id, use insertGetId to insert a
>   record and retrieve the id

Code Snippet

```
$id = DB::table('Document')->insertGetId($yourarray);
```

> **Note:** When using PostgreSQL the insertGetId method expects the
>   auto-incrementing column to be named "id".